# Last word in a sentence: In SQL (regular expressions possible?)

Tags: regex, algorithm, oracle, string, plsql

I need this to be done in Oracle SQL (10gR2). But I guess, I would rather put it plainly, any good, efficient algorithm is fine.

Given a line (or sentence, containing one or many words, English), how will you find the last word of the sentence?

Here is what I have tried in SQL. But, I would like to see an efficient way of doing this.

```
select reverse(substr(reverse(&p_word_in)
                         , 0
                         , instr(reverse(&p_word_in), ' ')
                         )
                  )
      from dual;
```

The idea was to reverse the string, find the first occurring space, retrieve the substring and reverse the string. Is it quite efficient? Is a regular expression available? I am on Oracle 10g R2. But I dont mind seeing any attempt in other programming language, I wont mind writing a PL/SQL function if need be.

### Update:

Jeffery Kemp has given a wonderful answer. This works perfectly.

#### Answer

```
SELECT SUBSTR(&sentence, INSTR(&sentence,' ',-1) + 1)
FROM dual
```

Comment: Ok, fine. A related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648133/regular-expression-to-find-last-word-in-sentence

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I reckon it's simpler with INSTR/SUBSTR:

```
WITH q AS (SELECT 'abc def ghi' AS sentence FROM DUAL)
SELECT SUBSTR(sentence, INSTR(sentence,' ',-1) + 1)
FROM q;
```

Comment: I am getting error: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
'INSTR' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @AnjanKant, that error indicates you're not using Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how it is performance wise, but this should do it:

```
select regexp_substr(&p_word_in, '\S+$') from dual;
```

Comment: This won't work if there is a period or other character at the end of the sentance, same goes for compie.

Comment: @Jesse: true, perhaps every non-whitespace character would be a better solution

Comment: select regexp_substr(&p_word_in, '[^\s]+$') from dual; or select regexp_substr(&p_word_in, '(\w+)[^\w]*$') from dual; should both work. The first will grab the period, the 2nd shouldn't (I'm not sure how parentheses are handled in oracle.)

Comment: @Jesse: for the record, `[^\s]` is the same as `\S` and `[^\w]` is the same as `\W` :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can use a regex in oracle, but wouldn't

(\w+)\W*$

work?

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches the last word on a line:

```
\w+$
```

And RegexBuddy gives this code for use in Oracle:

```
DECLARE
        match VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN
        match := REGEXP_SUBSTR(subject, '[[:alnum:]]_+$', 1, 1, 'c');
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

this leaves the punctuation but gets the final word

```
with datam as (
SELECT 'abc asdb.' A FROM DUAL UNION
select 'ipso factum' a from dual union
select 'ipso factum' a from dual union
SELECT 'ipso factum2' A FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 'ipso factum!' A FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 'ipso factum  !' A FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 'ipso factum/**//*/?.?' A FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 'ipso factum  ...??!?!**' A FROM DUAL UNION
select 'ipso factum ..d.../.>' a from dual 

)
SELECT a,
--REGEXP_SUBSTR(A, '[[:alnum:]]_+$', 1, 1, 'c') , /** these are the other examples*/
--REGEXP_SUBSTR(A, '\S+$') ,  /** these are the other examples*/
regexp_substr(a, '[a-zA-Z]+[^a-zA-Z]*$')  

from datam
```

Answer (score 0):

This works too, even for non english words :

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('San maria Calle Cáceres Numéro 25 principal izquierda, España', '[^ .]+$') FROM DUAL;
```