# Style on Last Words

Tags: css, styles, words

I have a long list of `<li>`s. A piece of JQuery code below helps me to style the last words of each `<li>`.  Please take a look [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CbJtu)

The issue now is I don't want it apply the style to the last `<li>`.

Could could I do that?

Here is my whole code.  Please take a look

```
<html>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('li').each(function(){
       var $this = $(this), text=$this.text().trim(), words = text.split(/\s+/);
       var lastWord = words.pop();
       words.push('<span class="Red">' + lastWord + '</span>');
       $this.html(words.join(' '));
   });
});
</script>
<style>
.Red{color:red}
</style>
<body>
<li>my holy tag galore</li>
<li>my sandwich is balloney</li>
<li>the expected is not to be </li>
<li>oh REALLY? </li>

<script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery-1.10.2.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: place your code on [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/) please

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see is your "Red" and "Bold" classes might not really be defined actually. I've tested your code myself and it works just fine - it adds the said classes to the last word.

However, just to keep it simple (um, alright ... for the RegEx's sake) you could use the *replace* function, just like this:

```
$('li').click(function(){
    var $t = $(this);
    $t.html($t.text().trim().replace(/(\w+)[.!?]?\s*$/, "<b>$1</b>"));
});
```

It surrounds the last word with `<b></b>` tags. Just replace them with whatever you like. The click event is also for the sake of testing, you can always change it to `each` function or anything else, really.

Here's a break down on how this RegEx actually works:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3648147/1368043

Comment: Thank you very much! But poor me, it doesn't work on me.

Here is the whole code:

    <html>
    
    <script>
    $('li').each(function(){
       var $this = $(this), text=$this.text().trim(), words = text.split(/\s+/);
       var lastWord = words.pop();
       words.push('<span class="Red">' + lastWord + '</span>');
       $this.html(words.join(' '));
    });
    </script>
    <style>
    .Red{color:red}
    </style>
    <body>
    <li> I need some help</li>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    
    </body>
    </html>

What I am missing here?  Thank you!

Comment: Mate, you're not making it any easier on me this way ... if you want to add some code, edit your original post, just look at this - it's a mess. If you want anybody to help you, you need to help them first.

Comment: Please tell me, how is it not working: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CbJtu
I'm telling you, your code works just fine, if it's not working for you, then provide us a **live** example where it does not, in a fiddle for example.

Comment: Thank you.  When the page is loaded, the red color should show up right away (don't need to click on the button). I just tried the buttons in the link you provided. How can I get it work without hitting the button?  Please give me a hand.  Thank you!

Comment: I ... I don't know what to say. I have this feeling as if you were living in your own world. Your code in the original post is 100% correct and if you are not able to modify the code I gave to you to accommodate your task, maybe you shouldn't have started fiddling around with JavaScript in the first place?

Comment: Hello Tomalla, I got it works now. Please take a look [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CbJtu).  The issue right now is I don't want it apply to the last `<li>`, how could I do that?

Comment: You could use something like this inside of your each function: `if($this.is("li:last")) return true;` That will successfully skip the current iteration of `each` function and thus - make the `li` element currently being iterated not painted.

Comment: May I know what was wrong in your previous setup? So that your code wouldn't work?

Comment: I just removed `function red()'` and replaced with `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: `if($this.is("li:last")) return true;` doesn't work, Tomalla!  Any suggestion?

Comment: Well, with the DOM not loaded there's no wonder nothing worked for you ... and my code does work, it just depends on its placement in the function, I hope you haven't put it straight at the end of the function? Otherwise, please give me a link to a **working** example, where it doesn't work.

Comment: Tomalla [This link](http://codepen.io/abcid/pen/vAupa) shows last words in red without any button.  And [this link](http://codepen.io/abcid/pen/ytGbJ) is after `if($this.is("li:last")) return true;` placed in.  It still applies RED in the last `<li>`.  Any suggestion?

Comment: Just analyze the code ... you're exiting the function after painting your last `li` red. What's the point of doing it in that order?

Comment: The issue now is I don't want it apply the style to the last `<li>`. Any suggestion? please

Comment: Yes indeed, I thought that was the subject of our discussion this whole time, now wasn't it?

Comment: No, we did go through every thing and after I put every `<li>` list on, the last `<li>` is a command and have to to avoid the red color at the end in this `<li>`.  Any suggestion

Comment: What a coincidence, in the 7th comment in this discussion there's a solution for the exact same problem! Now go ahead and try that.